# 'IdentityContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api2, mongodb-.net-driver

I am migrate the project https://github.com/attilah/AngularJSAuthentication to  using mongodb driver verson 2 , and I am in the final step here:

```
namespace AngularJSAuthentication.API
{
    using AspNet.Identity.MongoDB;
    using Entities;
    using MongoDB.Driver;

    public class ApplicationIdentityContext : IdentityContext
    {
        public ApplicationIdentityContext(IMongoContext mongoContext)
            : this(mongoContext.Users, mongoContext.Roles)
        {
        }

        public ApplicationIdentityContext(IMongoCollection<User> users, IMongoCollection<Role> roles)
            : base(users, roles)

        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get this error

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IdentityContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   AngularJSAuthentication.API D:\Projects\AngularJSAuthentication-master\AngularJSAuthentication.API\ApplicationIdentityContext.cs`

Here is my current source code

https://github.com/skanel/Angular2-WebApi2-Mongodb2-Authentication

UPDATED

@Swagata Prateek, thank for your code,however when I run the It stop working in direct me to this block of code in startup.cs

```
private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IContainer container)
        {
            var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Provider = container.Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = container.Resolve<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>()
            };
```

**Error**

> An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException'
>   occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred during the activation of a
>   particular registration. See the inner exception for details.
>   Registration: Activator = SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider
>   (ReflectionActivator), Services =
>   [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider],
>   Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared,
>   Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally used the same example for my Asp.net Identity implementation over Mongodb and the reason you're missing that class is because of the fact the sample is pretty old and the Identity extension for mongodb it depends on is [here](https://github.com/g0t4/aspnet-identity-mongo) and it has progressed to updated versions already.

I can't go with the full description here on how I used it but I surely can point you to my open source project [here](https://github.com/NerdCats/TaskCat/tree/master/TaskCat/TaskCat/Lib/Auth) where I've learned form the example that you mentioned. I hope it would solve your problem on implementing Asp.net Identity with Mongodb.

#### Update

1. If you want to have the exactly same solution that Attila Hajdrik wrote in the git repo please make sure you have exactly the same package version the AspNet.Identity.MongoDB defined [here](https://github.com/attilah/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/packages.config). Because the library itself is now upgraded itself and I presume you either updated all the nuget packages or recreated the whole solution written in the github repo according to your need. In both cases, you might end up with a version of AspNet.Identity.MongoDB you don't want to use. This one should be the shortest and easiest solution for your need.
2. Now on my solution mentioned above from my github repo. I used my own `IAccountContext` and I used `UserManager<User>` as my base AccountManager and `UserStore<User>` as my underlying store for the manager. Here `User` class is the Identity class that Im using which is derived from `IdentityUser`.

Technically you can build your own context out easily and you don't
    really have to rely on the given example to the fullest.

My sample AccountContext would be :

```
public class AccountContext : IAccountContext
{        
    private readonly IDbContext dbContext;
    private readonly AccountManager accountManager;

    public AccountContext(
        IDbContext dbContext,         
        AccountManager accoutnManager)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.accountManager = accoutnManager;        
    }
// Your own stuff here
}
```

Here, `AccountManager` is a `UserManager<T>` derivative and it takes a `IUserStore<User>` in it's constructor. It practically gives you more freedom on how you want to design your Identity layer. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Swagata - even if you can't include the full description, to make a good Stack Overflow answer you do need to at least partially describe your solution, perhaps with bullet-points. If your code on github is changed or re-engineered or moved elsewhere, then this answer needs to remain useful even without it.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry. I'd update my answer shortly and thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Thanks you for you response, here is my source trying on github: https://github.com/skanel/Angular2-WebApi2-Mongodb2-Authentication

Comment: Neat, would try to push a PR by tomorrow as I have some works to do today.

Comment: Sent a PR, please check out when you can.

Comment: And if the answer works, please mark my answer as the one for you please. :)

Comment: Please help to check my update after get your code run, I face with small issue, could you check what need to be done?

Comment: I need to know where you mentioned the small issue.  :)

Comment: Okay, I can see that you missed my comment in the PR, I did mention that I didn't take care of your dependency resolution issues.

Comment: Hi, I sent back another PR again, this is a dependency injection issue. I didn't check myself so kindly check it out yourself. This issue was about refactoring the sample code so it's usable again.

Comment: Added another commit in the PR. I hope your service runs up now. It was missing a `UserStore<User>` implementation. 

Anyway, have a great a day and hope your problem is solved. Please mark my suggestion as an answer if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this package versions are old and can be an issue be compatibility. If nothing is preventing you from updating, please do update the packages to latest versions.

When you do update, just FYI that IdentityContext does not exists anymore in the AspNet.Identity.MongoDb package/library. See source code in Github: https://github.com/g0t4/aspnet-identity-mongo

Comment: I did all update here is my try: https://github.com/skanel/Angular2-WebApi2-Mongodb2-Authentication