# Web api 2 and Mongodb v2 Migrate sample code to using driver version 2

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api2, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am trying to convert the project from here https://github.com/attilah/AngularJSAuthentication to using the mongo driver version 2 the  latest one so I can adapt to my current project.

I nearly completed of my migration  but I face with a few files which I dont know how to convert , because I new comming into the web api 2 and mongodb .

The problem which I am facing problem are:

1. ApplicationIdentityContext.cs
2. ApplicationUserManager.cs
3. ApplicationRoleManager.cs

For example with ApplicationIdentityContext.cs I have tried as the following code, but does error appear and I get stuck on this point:

```
namespace AngularJSAuthentication.API
{
    using Entities;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    public class ApplicationIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationIdentityContext(IMongoContext mongoContext)
            : this(mongoContext.Users, mongoContext.Roles)
        {
        }

        public ApplicationIdentityContext(IMongoCollection<User> users, IMongoCollection<Role> roles)
           : base(users, roles)

        {
       } 
    }
}
```

and then the editor show me error when I build the program :

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<AngularJSAuthentication.API.Entities.User>' to 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'   AngularJSAuthentication.API D:\Projects\AngularJSAuthentication-master\AngularJSAuthentication.API\ApplicationIdentityContext.cs    14  Active`

Here is my repos: https://github.com/skanel/Angular2-WebApi2-Mongodb2-Authentication

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This question looks like a possible duplicate to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914303/identitycontext-could-not-be-found-are-you-missing-a-using-directive-or-an-as/39042599#39042599)

I answered my two cents there. Care to have a look?

Comment: https://github.com/skanel/Angular2-WebApi2-Mongodb2-Authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is a breaking change from 1.9 to 2.+. The package

AspNet.Identity.MongoDB  is not compatible with the new mongo driver version 2+.

Hence the error: `'cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<AngularJSAuthentication.API.Entities.User>' to 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'`

Comment: any solution , I was tried here https://github.com/skanel/Angular2-WebApi2-Mongodb2-Authentication

Comment: I sent a PR to your repo, please check out.